# Is the following report feasible with Power BI?

Tags: report, powerbi

I am quite new to Power BI and don't have much knowledge about it. I got the requirement to develop a report exactly as it is in the legacy system. The report has integrated bullet charts in a table and a custom collection of dimensions / facts.

Here's a screenshot:
[image]

Would it be possible to come up with a Power BI solution for that report which resembles the original more than 90%?

My current report tool doesn't support bullet charts at all (hence I am trying Power BI). However with Power BI it seems that you cannot integrate visuals like bullet charts (tried https://okviz.com/bullet-chart/) into a table.

It would be helping if you could choose one of these answers:

- Yes, that's exactly what Power BI was made for and you can get it
  from mostly standard functionality within the tool.
- Yes, that's possible but you have to use some creative ways to come
  up with a solution.
- No, visuals, and tabular data are always two separate things in Power
  BI

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get duplicate the functionality pretty well, even if the exact formatting is a bit different.

Microsoft does have a [Bullet Chart Visual](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/WA104380755) that you can easily add to the out-of-the-box visualizations in Power BI using the `Import a custom visual` button. Here's a screenshot from the page I linked:

[image: Bullet Chart]

You can use the OKViz one you linked just as easily.

Whether you can get formatting that "resembles the original more than 90%" is unclear. I don't know how much of the style is required to match or how closely.